# Enforce jsx to start on new line if jsx is multiline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint, eslintrc

What eslint rule would prefer the former over the second when the jsx spans multiple lines?  Currently prettier is changing preferred to notPreferred

```
const preferred = (
    <tag
        prop={hi}
        another={test}
    \>
);

const notPreferred = (<tag
        prop={hi}
        Another={test}
    \>
);
```

Comment: Do you have more than one code formatter installed? It could be another one taking precedence

Comment: No, I manually select to format with prettier anyways and it still does the formatting where it’s “squished”

Comment: Can you post your current eslint and prettier configs?

Comment: With an empty eslint and prettier at default it still doesn’t format in preferred, I want “if there is more than one prop multilien the jsx and start the jsx on a beeline after the open parents”

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same, it seems that [react/jsx-wrap-multilines](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-wrap-multilines.md) rule covers that.

This means adding:

```
"react/jsx-wrap-multilines": ["error", {
   "declaration": "parens-new-line",
    "assignment": "parens-new-line",
    "return": "parens-new-line",
    "arrow": "parens-new-line",
    "condition": "parens-new-line",
    "logical": "parens-new-line",
    "prop": "parens-new-line"
  }
]
```

This does the job, and you can customize it in multiple ways, take a look at the documentation